# Weird splitter behaviour when moving it

Tags: silverlight, xaml, layout

My demo app displays two rectangles which should fill whole browser's screen. There is a vertical splitter between them. This looks like a basic scenario but I have no idea how to implement this in xaml. I cannot force this to fill whole screen and when moving splitter then whole screen grows. Can anybody help?

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"  
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>            
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="50">
        </Border>
        <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" ></controls:GridSplitter>
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="50"></Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridSplitter just sucks.  Try a docking control.

Comment: Yeah! It's better to avoid than to cure! At the office I decided to use Telerik's splitters. Built-in SL splitter doesn't exist for me!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It is your column layout. You need star-sizing for the left and right columns, and auto for the middle:</strike>

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

**EDIT:**

The correct way of using a grid splitter (in this particular case) appears to be to use just two columns in the grid. The grid splitter should then be placed in the *first* column, but aligned to the right. Like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="3"
                Margin="3,3,13,3"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                MinWidth="50">
        </Border>
        <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Width="10"></controls:GridSplitter>
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue"
                Margin="3"
                BorderThickness="3"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Grid.Column="2"
                MinWidth="50"></Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It helps a bit. Application fills whole screen but have you seen how it works when moving a splitter?

Comment: Yes, I see now. Sorry, I missed that. See the updated code above.

Answer (score 1):

I find that splitter and auto width just don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun sample page with silverlight samples.

http://www.xs4all.nl/~wrb/Articles/Article_WPFSplitPanels_01_SL.htm